# Text color picker in angular text editor directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, text-editor

I would like to use [textAngular](http://www.textangular.com/) directive, but I also need text color changing functionality, which as far as I know, is missing.

Is it really missing, or it's just an hidden option that i didn't find?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this **[Full Featured textAngular](https://github.com/mfrye/textAngular)**
which adds the following additional features to the existing plugin

- Colorpicker via angular-bootstrap-colorpicker
- Font family
- Font size
- Indent / outdent
- Added angular-ui bootstrap dropdown toggle to hold common items
- h1-h6 and p formatBlocks
- text alignment

Comment: Have you guys had any trouble installing the thing? Everything works except the color picker for me.

Comment: I too have not had success in getting the color picker to live.  I grabbed the code from the full featured textAngular and added the colorpicker using taRegisterTool, but alas no luck yet.:

Comment: The first thing I needed to do was to add the css from the colorpicker.

Comment: is their any textEditor which doesn't use `jquery`, i want font color change functionality without any jquery dependency

Comment: I am not able to use the full featured textAngular.... can someone show what additional files are to be added? It'll really help me and many others...